# Loop to gradually to remove elements to dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary that for example looks like this:

```
new_dict = {
    0: ['1'], 
    1: ['1', '2'], 
    2: ['1', '2', '3'], 
    3: ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 
    4: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 
    5: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
}
```

the values are just gradually appended, meaning that the next value contains the elements of the previous value + its own value.

and my question is, how can I, starting from key=3 included, remove gradually all the starting values?

so for example, for key=3, after the code the new key=3 should look like this:

```
3: ['2', '3', '4'] #Should remove the value of key=0
```

then for key=4, the new key=4 should look like this:

```
4: ['3', '4', '5'] #Should remove the value of key=1
```

And so on til the end of new_dict.

Comment: Do you need code to remove such items from an existing dictionary, or are you looking for code to generate such a dictionary (which would be easier) given certain starting values? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: in what senario is such dict useful?

Comment: Grismar, either options would work, thanks for the questions!

Comment: Lei Yang, I was collecting data to compute LGD for bank's clients who have been defaulted within 12 months. To make the collection easier I was pulling out info in chunks of clients numbers to do all at once sort of. And since I needed 12 months only (keys in this case would be the dates, and values - client ID's), I had to remove from the chunk the clients who were above 12 months. Hope I explained this properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relatively compact solution:

```
new_dict = {0: ['1'], 1: ['1', '2'], 2: ['1', '2', '3'], 3: ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 4: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 5: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}
up_dict={i:[item  for item in new_dict[i] if item not in new_dict[i-3]] if i>2 else new_dict[i] for i in new_dict}
print(up_dict)
```

Output:

```
{0: ['1'], 1: ['1', '2'], 2: ['1', '2', '3'], 3: ['2', '3', '4'], 4: ['3', '4', '5'], 5: ['4', '5', '6']}
```

Comment: nice answer. I think the op would like it to also contain the previous (0, 1, 2) unmodified key-value pairs too.

Comment: this was exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @David, most welcome! Consider accepting and up-voting the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the items and reassign the list to the last three elements:

```
In [1]: new_dict = {0: ['1'], 1: ['1', '2'], 2: ['1', '2', '3'], 3: ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 4: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 5: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}


In [2]: for k, v in new_dict.items():
   ...:     if len(v) > 3:
   ...:         new_dict[k] = v[-3:]
   ...:

In [3]: new_dict
Out[3]:
{0: ['1'],
 1: ['1', '2'],
 2: ['1', '2', '3'],
 3: ['2', '3', '4'],
 4: ['3', '4', '5'],
 5: ['4', '5', '6']}
```

As a dict comprehension:

```
out_dict = {k: v[-3:] if len(v) > 3 else v for k, v in new_dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job and be quite efficient as well, if that's important to you:

```
new_dict = {0: ['1'], 1: ['1', '2'], 2: ['1', '2', '3'], 3: ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 4: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 5: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}
print({key:(value,value[key-2:])[key//3] for key,value in new_dict.items()})
>>> {0: ['1'], 1: ['1', '2'], 2: ['1', '2', '3'], 3: ['2', '3', '4'], 4: ['3', '4', '5'], 5: ['4', '5', '6']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension, and take the key value pair as it is if key<3 else take only the items that are not in the values for key at 0,1,2, and so on.

```py
{k:new_dict[k] if idx<0 else [i 
                              for i in new_dict[k] if i not in new_dict[idx]] 
 for idx,k in enumerate(new_dict, -3)}
```

OUTPUT:

```py
{0: ['1'],
 1: ['1', '2'],
 2: ['1', '2', '3'],
 3: ['2', '3', '4'],
 4: ['3', '4', '5'],
 5: ['4', '5', '6']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter comprehension-based solution:

```
new_dict = {0: ['1'], 1: ['1', '2'], 2: ['1', '2', '3'], 3: ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 4: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], 5: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']}
c = 0
r = {a:b if a < 3 else b[(c:=c+1):] for a, b in new_dict.items()}
```

Output:

```
{0: ['1'], 1: ['1', '2'], 2: ['1', '2', '3'], 3: ['2', '3', '4'], 4: ['3', '4', '5'], 5: ['4', '5', '6']}
```